# the call is ambiguous between the same methods Asp.Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I tried to edit a GridView in one of the pages of my site, topics.aspx. I decided to change the DataSourceID, from the one I put in design view on the grid view, with a custom one, following this tutorial

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/9f0ae2/gridview-edit-delete-and-update-in-asp-net/?authorFollow=true-9f0ae2-article&name=neha-sharma52

I COPIED and PASTED the exact SqlConnection from the register.aspx.cs page, which is

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

as a private field in topic.aspx.cs.

Suddenly, my register page doesn't work anymore. The "SqlConnection" in

```
new SqlConnection(...)
```

call is "ambigous" between

```
SqlConnection.SqlConnection(string)
```

and

```
SqlConnection.SqlConnection(string)
```

I undid everything I did, obviously. My last resort is to delete topics.aspx and topics.aspx.cs altogether, but... will it work then? I highly doubt did.

I don't know what i did wrong, I only copied and pasted a line of code, and suddenly, my register.aspx and login.aspx don't work anymore. What is the problem?

EDIT:
The imports I am using are

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

Comment: Do you have your own `SqlConnection` class somewhere?

Comment: I don't. I am still a noob, I wouldn't define my own SqlConnection class. I deleted topic.aspx and topix.aspx.cs, still no result

Comment: If you just declare a variable of type `SqlConnection`, e.g. `SqlConnection connection = null;` and then hover over the variable name, does it show you a fully-qualified type name?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes, it's (local variable)SqlConnection connection

Comment: Sorry, try hovering over the `SqlConnection` part instead - again, I'm trying to make sure that it's using the right fully-qualified type name. It should show `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`.

Comment: May sound silly, but did you try restarting Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

If your connection string doesn't use **Integrated Security = true** you can try SqlConnection(String, SqlCredential) or just call default constructor

Comment: It should be fine just to call `SqlConnection(string)` though.